# How can many duplicates of the same question be handled?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There was recently a bug/new feature on [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium), related to Chrome not distributing the drivers on the same URL, and [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) now automatically fetching the driver from the installed browser. This lead to tens of questions being created specifically for this problem in Python.

I have 10 links to such questions, but either the question is badly asked, or the answers are not good.

- **Best question:** [Error : "cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:54613 from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76958243/error-cannot-connect-to-chrome-at-127-0-0-154613-from-session-not-created-t)
- **Best answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/76914590/12134355
- [session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76909437/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-1)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76925094/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea)
- [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 using latest Chromium v116.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458337/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome)
- [This Version Of ChromeDriver Only Supports 114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931794/this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-114)
- [session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942407/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-1)
- [Chrome Driver tells that supports 114 version but it should support the 113 one - Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76869242/chrome-driver-tells-that-supports-114-version-but-it-should-support-the-113-one)

How should this be handled? I would request a merge between Best Question and Best Answer, then mark other questions as duplicates, but I'm unsure if this is the correct course of action.

---

**Edit:** As said in the comments, while I would normally have improved formatting on the question with the Best Answer then marked others as duplicates, it is very badly asked — actually not even a question, but rather an answer to the title — which makes it unsalvageable. Likewise, the best question doesn't have a valid sustainable answer, so I won't flag others as duplicates of this one.

**Explanation for "no valid sustainable answer":** Most answers in these question mention manually downloading the latest chrome driver and adding it to the PATH, or manually downgrading Chrome to match the driver version. None of these answers are valid because the former means you have to download the new driver for every Chrome Browser update and the latter means you are staying behind some updates. The most valid answer is to update the `selenium` module as the latest version will automatically fetch the correct driver for you (this was previously feasible by installing another module, which you might find in older answers too but which are now outdated).

Comment: As somebody without a gold badge yet you can add to the list of duplicates so use the question with the best answer as the duplicate for all the other questions and let somebody with a gold badge mark the questions without an answer as a duplicate of the closed question (but have an answer) as additional duplicate.

Comment: As I said in my post, that's what I would have done but the question with the best (& correct) answer is very badly asked and unsalvageable without changing author's intent, hence my question here and probably a merge

Comment: The fact that the question is badly asked is unfortunate but not exactly a blocker according to the current ruling surrounding dupe closure; all roads must lead to the best answer, not the best question. Essentially what we do is link people to a question and then essentially say "The answer is in there somewhere. Good luck!".

Comment: @Gimby I strongly disagree, the question isn't even a question but an answer to the title, making it very prone to being closed/deleted.

Comment: *Normally* I would say "fix the question associated with the best answer, then use that"; but that one is so badly done (it's presenting a bad answer to an unasked question) that it's hard to imagine a suitable edit that wouldn't completely redo it.

Comment: Maybe ask the person who posted the best answer to post his answer on the best question, and then mark all the others dups of that one.

Comment: We should close all duplicates to the "Best question", then flag so a mod can merge the question(s) with the best answer(s) to the best question. Bad questions with good answers can still be closed for other reasons (unclear, too broad etc), no matter how many duplicates point to them, so why should we let answers drive question duplication? The best written question is the one most likely to capture traffic from search engines and should therefore be the "front door" to the best answers our community can provide.

Comment: @Robotnik Sounds like the best course of action but need to flag for merge before, then mark others as duplicate ;) — I'm going to do that

Comment: Oh well, a 20k user completely edited the question with the best answer, so I guess...